# Range of "global_quality" value for h264_qsv encoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, codec, h.264

What is the range of the `-global_quality` setting for ffmpeg's `h264_qsv` encoder (4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build-www.gyan.dev, Windows)?

Ffmpeg's [documentation for the encoder](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#QSV-encoders) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210703224808/https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#QSV-encoders)) states:

> The ratecontrol method is selected as follows:
>
> - When global_quality is specified, a quality-based mode is used. Specifically this means either
>
>   - CQP - constant quantizer scale, when the qscale codec flag is also set (the -qscale ffmpeg option).
>   - LA_ICQ - intelligent constant quality with lookahead, when the look_ahead option is also set.
>   - ICQ – intelligent constant quality otherwise.

But it doesn't state what the values mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CQP mode, `global_quality` is divided by 118 (let's call this `quant`) and then quantization parameters are computed as per frame type.

For I-frames, QP is `quant * 0.8, clipped to between 0 and 51`.
For P-frames, QP is `quant, clipped to between 0 and 51`.
For B-frames, QP is `quant * 1.25 + 1.25, clipped to between 0 and 51`.

For the ICQ modes, quality is the global_quality, clipped to between 1 and 51.

Comment: Thanks. In cursory testing this seems to be correct. Also I found some corroborating info buried in https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/advanced-bitrate-control-methods-in-intel-media-sdk.html.

Comment: Oh also I just checked your info page, and realized your username is in my version string, so I probably didn't really need to confirm that info, heh. Appreciate it.